# Count all comments including nested in Timber

Tags: wordpress, timber

Is there a way to get a count of all comments that belong to a post including nested comments? Currently I can do

`{{post.comments|length}}`

but that only gives me parent comments. I guess I could use one of wordpress built in functions but I'm wondering if there's a better wasy using Timber and `CommentThread`? The other option would be to recursively count the comments myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `post.comment_count`.

Comment: Late 2021 update: In the current version of Timber (1.19.1) it's `get_comment_count`. See: https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#get_comment_count